# Grails 1.3.7 dependency resolution error with quartz:1.0-RC1 plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

After I execute `grails compile` in my project, it show me:

```
plugin /home/deploy/.ivy2/cache/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/jars/quartz-1.8.4.jar is not a valid Grails plugin. No plugin.xml descriptor found!
```

I think that maybe the problem can be that the plugin name is "quartz" and the dependency of the plugin is "quartz:1.8.4" and maybe grails [get confused with the name](https://onekilo79.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/grails-1-3-x-and-plugin-dependency-name-conflict-resolution/).

Answer (score 0):

Your `BuildConfig.groovy` file should contain the correct version of quartz that you're trying to compile with. For instance, there should be a line in there that says:

```
compile ":quartz:1.8.4"
```

Where your version comes after the colon. Make sure that the plugin version you have installed matches this.

I would suggest doing a `grails clean` in your main project folder to make sure that everything is good, and if need be, re-install the plugin, and try rebuilding.

Comment: My project already have quartz-1.8.4.jar in the lib directory

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, this worked for me: 1) remove any plugin entry on quartz 1.0-RC1 in application.properties, 2) add in BuildConfig:
compile "org.grails.plugins:quartz:1.0-RC1"
to get it from maven instead.